# Is there any technology similar to LINQPad for compiling C# that runs in a browser?

Tags: c#

Think [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  LINQPad is pretty sweet for fast C# with similar options.  Is there anything like LINQPad that runs in a browser?

Comment: http://ideone.com has an online C# setting that uses the Mono compiler, but it doesn't have a lot of the bells and whistles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try [www.compilr.com](http://compilr.com/).  According to their website, Compilr is an online IDE, allowing you to write and compile code for a variety of platforms from any major web browser.

I've tried it out, it works fairly well. It supports C#, Ruby, C, Java and others.

Comment: FYI: compilr.com has been aquired by lynda.com and, consequently, shut down their services.

Answer (score 4):

[Run Code](http://rextester.com/runcode) is a very lightweight alternative that should work in any browser.

It does not require an account like [compilr](http://compilr.com/) and the interface is even more slimmed down than [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: Single line answer are generally frowned upon here on stack exchange. Could you expand your answer with why you think this option is a better fit than the other answers here?

Comment: @Mark_Booth Do you have any reference for the general frowning upon one-liners? The only related information I could find was http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/one-line-answers , which seems to disagree. Nevertheless, a comparison is of course a good idea; I added some info regarding that.

Comment: It's in the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) for every stack exchange site. One line answers are often *barely more than a link to an external site*, which makes them candidates for deletion. Your answer appeared in my review stream for *low quality posts* saying "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**.". Although I thought it had useful information (so didn't want to recommend deletion) I did think it needed improvement, hence my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything like that, but the reason JSFiddle is practical is because the code is run natively on the browser, not the server. In order to do something similar for C# code, you would most likely need to do so on the server or use a browser plugin.

A plugin solution would defeat the purpose of even being browser-based because it would require an installation and limit the platforms it can run on. A server-based solution would have many inherent risks unless it were heavily sandboxed.